# Are these bases for a topology?

Tags: general-topology

I have the following topology :
$$\tau= \Bigl\{U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2: (\forall(a,b) \in U) (\exists  \epsilon >0) \bigl([a,a+\epsilon] \times [b-\epsilon, b+\epsilon]\subseteq U\bigr)\Bigr\}$$

Are these a basis for the previous topology:

$\beta_1= \{[a,a+\epsilon] \times [b-\epsilon, b+\epsilon]\subseteq \Bbb R^2: (a,b)\in \Bbb R^2, \epsilon>0 \}$

$\beta_2= \{[a,a+\epsilon) \times [b-\epsilon, b+\epsilon)\subseteq \Bbb R^2: (a,b)\in \Bbb R^2, \epsilon>0 \}$

The first one is obviously a basis for $\tau$ because of the definition of $\tau$
and I would say that the second is also a basis, because $[a,a+\epsilon) \times [b-\epsilon, b+\epsilon) \subseteq [a,a+\epsilon] \times [b-\epsilon, b+\epsilon] 
$

Is it correct? what do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that no element in $\beta_1$ is actually an open set in the topology $\tau$. Consider the element $A$ in $\beta_1$ with $a=b=0$ and $\epsilon=1$. The point $(1,1)\in A$ but there exists no $\epsilon>0$ such that $[1,1+\epsilon]\times[1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon]\subset A$ because $(1,1)$ is on the boundary of $A$.

For $\beta_2$, consider the same $a,b,\epsilon$ but look at the point $(0,0)$.

Comment: So none of them are a basis? I don't understand why the first one isn't. I have to prove that for any $U\in \tau$ any $(a.b)\in U$, exists $B_{(a,b)}\in \beta_1: (a,b)\in B_{(a,b)}\subseteq U$ And why does not satisfy this?

Comment: The elements of $\beta_1$ are not open in $\tau$, which is a necessary condition for $\beta_1$ to be a basis of $\tau$ (by any normal definition of basis anyway). Check my example $A$ above. It does not satisfy the conditions necessary to be an element of $\tau$.

Comment: The definition you mention is not the usual definition of a basis of a topology. It's not even equivalent to the normal definition because otherwise the set of closed intervals would form a basis for the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Which is the problem with the point (0,0)?? Taking a=b= 0 and $\epsilon=0$ we get that A=[0,1)x[-$\epsilon, \epsilon$], and for the point (0,0), [0,$\epsilon$]x [-$\epsilon$, $\epsilon$] is part of A isn't it?

Comment: @Blanca: You should look at the point $(0,-1)\in[0,1)\times[-1,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** What definition of “basis” are you using?  There are a few variations of the definition around, but all the ones I know start by requiring that **the sets in the basis should themselves be open sets** of the topology.  It’s easy to jump straight to checking the other properties, but it’s important not to forget that first condition.